# ListView background click

Tags: android, onclick, android-listview

I'm trying to handle an onClick event when the user tries to click the background in my empty listView - i.e. No items.  the ADK doesn't want to allow me to add an onClickListener to the ListView, and instead insists that adding an onItemClickListener is the way to go - but obviously this won't work for an empty list.  I am using a ListActivity with an xml descriptor for the listItems.

Can anyone please advise the best way to do this?

```
   <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:item_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some view, that will be shown, when your list is empty. This view have to have id "empty". (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)
Try to add onClick for this special view.

Comment: Like the idea, but concerned that the user might hit the back button, taking them back to my empty (unclickable) list.  Any other ideas?

Comment: if user hit the back button, he/she leaves the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/emptyList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ListView />
</FrameLayout>
```

In your Java code you can then add an onClickListener to your emptyList object, which returns false if the ListView has an item count greater than 0 (Allowing the click to pass down the view heirarchy and be picked up by your `onItemClickListener`).

Answer (score 0):

In the layout which has the ListView add this:

```
<ListView 
android:id="@android:id/list" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
/>

<TextView 
android:id="@android:id/empty" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:text="No Results" 
/>
```

now add onClickListener to this TextView.

This TextView is shown automatically when the ListView with id as `@android:id/list` is empty or not yet populated